# Indian passport holder working at European branch. Do I need a visa to work at US branch and if so, which one?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, working-visas

I am an Indian passport holder working in the German branch of my office on a valid work permit. If my company wants to send me to the US for work, do I need a visa? If yes, what is the visa and how fast can I get it?

If no visa is required, does it come under the ESTA program?

Comment: If you're in a large enough company, there are probably people in HR able to assist you with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an Indian citizen, you require a visa to visit the United States. Indian citizens are not eligible for the Visa Waiver Program (which requires ESTA).

[A business visa (B-1)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) allows you to come to the US temporarily (usually up to six months, often much less) for [certain permitted business purposes](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf), such as attending meetings or training. It does not allow you to work in the US at all, and you generally cannot receive any income from a US entity. [The wait time for an appointment](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html) at the US Embassy in Berlin or Munich is currently 6-7 days.

If you don't qualify for a B-1 visa because you actually need to work in the United States, you will need [an employment visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment.html). There are several types of these, depending on your position and circumstances, and all require a fair amount of effort to secure, if you are even eligible (often months-years; if you qualify for an [L-visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/l-1a-intracompany-transferee-executive-or-manager) and your company pays through the nose, it can be a few weeks once the paperwork is done). For an employment visa, a US company must submit a petition on your behalf; they will generally hire an immigration lawyer to assist them with this.

If you're unsure what type of visa you need after reviewing [the US State Department's information on visas](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas.html), your company should consult a US immigration lawyer.

Comment: Are there any special kind of VISAs, which can allow me to work in US for short term, as me being a EU(even though I am INDIAN citizen) employee?

Comment: There isn't any special kind of visa that would apply to you as an employee in the EU. The same rules would apply if you were a German citizen, except you would be able to use the Visa Waiver Program instead of a B-1 visa, but only for the same allowed business purposes. If you don't qualify for a B-1 visa, you'd need an employment visa, if you're eligible.

Comment: If they're sending you between the German branch and the US branch of the same company, an [L-1A](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/l-1a-intracompany-transferee-executive-or-manager) or [L-1B](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/l-1b-intracompany-transferee-specialized-knowledge) visa may be appropriate, if you can prove you're an executive/manager or have the necessary "specialized knowledge." It's common to hire a lawyer to prepare that application if you qualify.

Comment: thank you very much for the information, I qualify for L1A